# How do I use Austin to profile a Python program from the command line

Tags: python, profiling, vscode-tasks

I need to profile a Python program from VSCode. This is not working and I am looking at the command line created by VSCode for the run.

```
> austin -i 100 --pipe /usr/bin/python3 /Users/mh/p131.py

 It looks like you are trying to profile a process that is not a Python
process. Make sure that you are targeting the right application. If the Python
process is actually a child of the target process then use the -C option to
discover it automatically.
```

The -C option is not helping either

```
> austin -i 100 -C --pipe /usr/bin/python3 /Users/mh/p131.py
 Not a Python process.

 It looks like you are trying to profile a process that is not a Python
process, and that has not spawned any child Python processes. Make sure that
you are targeting the right application.
```

This is on a MacBook running Monterey. The Austin application I downloaded was compiled for Apple silicon.

Tried command line after using VSCode. Tried suggested use of -C option on command line.

Comment: If this is on a mac, Austin won't work with the system Python installation (see https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin#on-macos-1). Otherwise, please open an issue on https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin/issues